# jQuery multiple variables in for loops

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

This might be simple thing but just can't figure it out.

Let's assume I got fifty similar functions and there's two of them:

```
var unit = ['red', 'pink']
var unit2 = ['red2', 'red2']

$('#red').click(function() {
if($('#red2').is(':hidden')) {
$('#red2').toggle();
} else {
$('#red2').toggle();}}}
```

and

```
$('#pink').click(function() {
if($('#pink2').is(':hidden')) {
$('#pink2').toggle();
} else {
$('#pink').toggle();}}}
```

and I want to add all these functions in one/two for loops.
I tried this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < unit.length; i++) {
for (var y = 0; y < unit2.length; y++) {
$('#i').click(function() {
if($('#y').is(':hidden')) {
$('#y').toggle();
} else {
$('#y').toggle();}}}}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but why do you even need `if` when the code in its branches is identical?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.toggle()` method detects the visibility of the element itself, there is no need to use `if` statement, you can use `this` keyword which refers to the clicked element:

```
$('#red, #pink').on('click', function() {
   // Based on the id property of the clicked element 
   // this selects #red2 or #pink2 element
   $('#' + this.id + '2').toggle();
});
```

Also note that `$('#i')` selects an element with ID of `i`, you should concatenate the strings:

```
$('#' + i).foo();
```

Comment: Yes, the `toggle()` was there because I used earlier `css('visibility','hidden')` method. But this seems to fit my needs, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should concatenate strings:

```
for (var i = 0; i < unit.length; i++) {
  $('#' + unit[i])
  .attr('data-dst', unit2[i])
  .click(function() {
    var dst = $(this).attr('data-dst');
    $('#' + dst).toogle();
  }
}
```

Comment: Loop variable problem!

Comment: `y === unit2.length` by the time the `click` handler will run.